# font-feature-settings and -webkit-font-smoothing all in one fix for font look

Tags: css, fonts

I have downloaded one html theme in which I have seen this code on body tag. now I know little bit about antialiased and grayscale but what is kern ? and what is exactly a use of this all code ? can anyone guide ?

is there any simple common fix for all font issues ? so fonts look same in all the browser

```
font-synthesis: none;
-webkit-font-feature-settings: 'kern';
font-feature-settings: 'kern';
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

Comment: [Kerning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning). In all honesty I don't think you need to about any of [these](https://davidwalsh.name/font-smoothing) unless you are really interested. You want a font to look the same on all modern browsers? your best bet is [WOFF](https://caniuse.com/#feat=woff) format fonts.

Answer (score 0):

*Sample*

```
html {
/* Adjust font size */
font-size: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
/* Font varient */
font-variant-ligatures: none;
-webkit-font-variant-ligatures: none;
/* Smoothing */
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .01) 0 0 1px;
```

}

***Reading materials***

[Antialiased](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/antialiasing-101/)

[Kern For The Web](http://adamdscott.com/kerning-for-the-web/)

[Font Kerning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-kerning)

[Kerning On The Web](https://blog.typekit.com/2014/02/05/kerning-on-the-web/)